# ASP.Net MVC Dropdown list group-wise

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, drop-down-menu

I am developing a MVC application. In my application I need to create a dropdown list group by continent. Like

1. Asia

   2. India
   3. Chaina
   4. Bangladesh
2. North America

   6. USA
   7. Canada
3. Europe

   9. UK
   10. France
   11. Spain
   12. Germany

etc.

In have created a single table to contain Continents and countries just maintain a parent and child relationship between them.

So my model is like:

```
public partial class String
{
    public int IID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
    public int IType { get; set; }
}
```

Here parentId is the null for Continents and Countries have the Continent id (IID which is PK) as parent id.

My controller is like

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var ContinentList = db.Strings.Where(c => c.IType == 1).ToList();
            IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> countriesByContinent = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>();

            foreach (var continent in ContinentList)
            {
                var countryList = new List<SelectListItem>();

                foreach (var country in db.Strings.Where(c => c.ParentId == continent.IID))
                {
                    countryList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = country.IID.ToString(), Text = country.Name });
                }

                countriesByContinent.Add(continent.Name, countryList);
            }

            ViewBag.CountriesList = countriesByContinent;
            return View();
        }
```

The .cshtml is like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IID, new SelectList(ViewBag.CountriesList as IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<SelectListItem>>), "[Please select a country]")
```

But I am getting following output
[image]

Only Continents are showing with garbage.

Database table script is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Strings](
    [IID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [IType] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Strings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Thanks
Partha

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using (this is only supported in MVC 5 and then you must set the `GroupName` property of `SelectListItem`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are turning it into a viewlist once in the controller and then again in the view. Just cast it back in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IID, ViewBag.CountriesList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "[Please select a country]")
```